# Does WebElement class inherits from WebDriver class in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, inheritance, webdriver, findelement

Sample code:

```
score_both_halves = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@data-btn-radio="\'ScoreBothHalves\'"]')
score_both_halves.find_element_by_xpath()
```

In the second line of code I used a `find_element_by_xpath()` method of `Webdriver` class with `WebElement` object and it works fine.

How is that possible? Is `WebElement` class inherits from `WebDriver` class in selenium python?

Isn't the WebElement class inherits from WebDriver class in selenium python? If not then how we can use methods of WebDriver class with WebElement object?

Comment: They just have their own methods of similar names

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) [Python binding documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html):

- The [Remote WebDriver implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver) contains the method [find_element()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element)

  - Usage:

    ```
    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')
    ```
  - Return type:

    ```
    WebElement
    ```
- Similarly The [Remote WebElement implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) also includes the method [find_element()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element)

  - Usage:

    ```
    element = element.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')
    ```
  - Return type:

    ```
    WebElement
    ```

---

### Conclusion

Hence `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')` and `element.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')` both are valid lies of code.

Comment: Any feedback for this answer?